# How to negate inside a case

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I'm a bit new in plsql, so could you tell me it exists a way to negate a case?
I mean, this way:

```
 select CASE DENOM_CURRENCY_CODE
            WHEN != 'MXN' THEN 'convert to USD'
            ELSE TO_CHAR(QUANTITY) --keep the quantity
        END
```

I received this messaage "ORA-00936: missing expression" I´ve tried too with "<>" and "not".
Thanks for reading

Comment: Did the answer I gave help you?

Comment: There are two forms: `case x when y then` ('simple case') and `case when x = y then` (searched case). You want the second one.

Comment: Also, for your particular example you could just switch your conditions, since you only have one - `case DENOM_CURRENCY_CODE when 'MXN' then to_char(quantity) else 'convert to USD' end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure for this type of expression is

```
Case when "expression" then
  //do something
Else
  //do something else 
End
```

In your case it should be

```
 select CASE when DENOM_CURRENCY_CODE
     != 'MXN' THEN 'convert to USD'
 ELSE TO_CHAR(QUANTITY) --keep the quantity
 END
```